# Getting an Import Error While trying to Run Cron Job with Django App

Tags: python, django, linux, cron, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a CRON job to run a script every minute however I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Inside my `crontab -e` command:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /Users/user/Documents/Program/App/manage.py command
```

Running this my terminal says I get new mail every minute but when I click on the message I get the above importError. I am using a .env file at the root of my directory to keep my API keys secure but I don't think that's important.I'm also not using a virtual environment at the moment but I have tried and however I can't find the correct python version installed into the virtual environment.

Running this command `python3 ./manage.py command` from the command works as expected which is why this is really confusing.

Comment: if you created project in `venv` (virtual environment) then you have to find path to `python` in this `venv` and use it in cron. You can't use global python if it has no installed Django. Activate venv and use `which python` or `which python3` to get path to python used in project.

Comment: at start you could run script which show all information about python, environment, user, etc. and run it in cron (and redirect output to file) - this way you will see if `cron` runs it as you or as other user with different privileges. Cron may also start python in different folder then you expect and it may not find `.env` - so better find path to python used in venv - something similar to `/Users/user/Documents/Program/lib/bin/python3`